# replace the NA value

Tags: r

In the following case I want to replace the `NA` with the corresponding `z` column value. How do I assign it?

```
df<-data.frame(x=c(1,2,3,4,5,NA,7,NA,9,10),
               z=c(1:10))
```

With this code I the `NA` is replaced with starting z value (1 and 2) and I need (6 and 8).

```
df$x[is.na(df$x)] <- (df$z)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use same the logic on the rhs

```
df$x[is.na(df$x)] <- df$z[is.na(df$x)]
```